# how to add MtProtoKit and login telegram iOS example

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, telegram

I want to make a telegram client for iOS devices.

i searched a lot in stackoverflow and internet for this issue .

i found telegram source code for iOS which its not possible to compile on Xcode 8.

i think there is a possible way and that is download Xcode 7.x or later to compile the code on it .
but its not a true act i think ..

i just need to know , how can i add the MtProtoKit in my project in Xcode and use it.

im beginner in iOS developing and im just trying to make a little program that if i gave a message contain "DO_SOME_THING" , my application do something for me for example ..

because of that i dont need all extra part of telegram source code .

.

how can i interact to telegram server via iOS devices?
is it just mtProtoKit problem ?
can i use it on Xcode 8 ?
it there any better way that it ?
what do i need to make a simple telegram client ?

special big thanks for sharing your knowledge with me and others.
thanks

Comment: Hi, have you figured out how to do it?